# Using JS to Change CSS Style Based on Content From Another Website on Arduino Yún

Tags: javascript, css, arduino

I have a question that ultimately (hopefully?) comes down to JS, but since I'm working on an Arduino Yún, I think it might be best to show that side of the problem so as to not leave anything out. Those willing to read my completely unentertaining explanation of something that doesn't really have much to do with the problem at hand, feel free to do so. Everybody else, follow me! +skips to **JS Problem**+

**Yún side**

Here's the deal: I want to change the css properties of a webpage hosted on the Yún based on some switches connecting PIN2 and PIN3 to GND.

I used the Bridge example as a basis to my code on the Arduino side of the thing, and I believe that's set up as it should be:

```
#include <Bridge.h>
#include <YunServer.h>
#include <YunClient.h>
//variable constante que guarda la cantidad de puertas

#define CANT_PUERTAS 2

//variable tipo array que guarda los estados de las diferentes puertas
int estado[CANT_PUERTAS];

YunServer server;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Bridge startup
  Bridge.begin();

  //Pines que van a monitorear las puertas
  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP);

  server.listenOnLocalhost();
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  //hacer poll de estado de puertas
  pollPuertas(estado, CANT_PUERTAS);

  YunClient client = server.accept();

  if (client) {
    process(client);
    client.stop();
  }

  delay(50); 
}
```

...with

```
void pollPuertas(int estado[], int arraySize) {
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        estado[i] = digitalRead(2 + i);
  }
}
```

...and

```
void process(YunClient client) {
  String command = client.readStringUntil('/');
  if (command == "estado") {
    int puerta = client.parseInt();
    client.print(estado[puerta]);
  }
}
```

So, the basic idea behind the code is as follows:
CANT_PUERTAS is the amount of PINs I want to monitor, and estado[] is an array where I will save the values of those pins.

Function `pollPuertas` is a simple `for loop` that reads the states of the PINs (in my case, I'm reserving PIN0 and PIN1 for future communication, so I start with PIN2) and saves those states to estado[].

Function `process` handles the REST calls. My calls are organized like this COMMAND/NUMBER, although I only mean to use one command right now. So, if my command is "estado", I simply use the NUMBER as the index of my array and print the value of that PIN to the client.

There are no issues with this code. If I access arduinoyun.local/arduino/estado/NUMBER, I get the expected results:

- a 1 for an open switch, or
- a 0 for a closed switch.

**The JS Problem**

Still with me? wow. Thanks :D.

For those who didn't read the previous part, here is a really simple review:

- I have two switches (as in light switches, not networking switches) I am monitoring.
- I've set up two "webpages" (one for each switch) whose contents change according to whether or not the switches are closed. These are hosted on the local network.
- The content of the "webpages" is either a 1 or a 0. ASCII. No HTML headers or anything, which is why I call them "webpages".

Now comes the actual problem. I'm pretty new to HTML, JS, and JQuery so please bear with me.

I want to host a simple website on the  Arduino Yún, whose CSS properties change according to the status of the switches. My idea was to write a script that would use an `if` conditional to evaluate how to change these properties. This script would be called on periodically so that the website reflects the changes in the switches' states in "real-time".

Here's my attempt at this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Poll de Puertas</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">    </script>
<!--    <script type="text/javascript"     src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js"></script>-->

    <script type="text/javascript">        
        function cambiarColor(){
        //  if($http.get("arduinoyun.local/arduino/estado/1") === 0){
            if(1==0){
                $('p:nth-child(1)').css('color','green');
            } else{
                $('p:nth-child(1)').css('color','red');
            }

            $('p:nth-child(2)').css('color','blue');
        }
    </script>

  </head>
    <body onload ="setInterval(cambiarColor,3000);">
    <p id="puerta1">Puerta 1</p>
    <p id="puerta2">Puerta 2</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

In the body I have 2 `<p>` elements, one for each switch. Function `cambiarColor` is my script in charge of changing the colors of the `<p>`s using the `if` conditional and some simple JQuery.

In this attempt, I managed to at least get the logic working: the first `<p>` is always changed to red because the `if` always evaluates to `FALSE`. Also, the function is called on periodically as well. The second `<p>` I just left out of the party because he called me a fattie ;(

**Now, what I don't know, and the real question behind this long-arse post, is what to put inside the `if()` in my script so that it pulls the value from the "webpage" I've set up (be it a 1 or a 0) so that the script responds to the states of the switches.**

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, many thanks to Q_ro for his help.

Here's how I managed to solve my problem:
In the same order as last time, first comes the **Arduino code**

```
#include <Bridge.h>
#include <YunServer.h>
#include <YunClient.h>

//variable constante que guarda la cantidad de puertas
#define CANT_PUERTAS 2

//variable tipo array que guarda los estados de las diferentes puertas
int estado[CANT_PUERTAS];

// Listen on default port 5555, the webserver on the Yun
// will forward there all the HTTP requests for us.
YunServer server;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Bridge startup
  Bridge.begin();
  //Pines que van a monitorear las puertas a partir de D2
  for (int i = 0; i < CANT_PUERTAS; i++) {
    pinMode(2 + i, INPUT_PULLUP);
  }
  // Listen for incoming connection only from localhost
  // (no one from the external network could connect)
  server.listenOnLocalhost();
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  //hacer poll de estado de puertas
  pollPuertas(estado);

  // Get clients coming from server
  YunClient client = server.accept();

  // There is a new client?
  if (client) {
    // Process request
    process(client);

    // Close connection and free resources.
    client.stop();
  }

  delay(50); // Poll every 50ms
}
```

My only changes here were in `void setup(){}`, where instead of manually declaring the pins to monitor, I created a `for loop` to automatically set them up based on the amount of pins to monitor; and in `pollPuertas`, where I changed the arguments passed to it.

```
void pollPuertas(int estado[]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < CANT_PUERTAS; i++) {
    estado[i] = digitalRead(2 + i);
  }
}
```

Like I said before, I changed the arguments to this function. Decided to just go with my previously defined constant.

```
void process(YunClient client) {
  // read the command
  String command = client.readStringUntil('/');
  command.trim();
  //confirmar que el comando recibido es el correcto
  if (command == "estado") {
    client.println("Status: 200");
    client.println("Content-type: application/json");
    client.println();
    //Inicio del array JSON
    client.print("[");
    //Valores del array
    for (int i = 0; i < CANT_PUERTAS; i++) {
      client.print(estado[i]);
      //Si no es el ultimo valor del array, intercalar una coma
      if (i < (CANT_PUERTAS - 1)) client.print(",");
    }
    //Cerrar array JSON
    client.print("]");
  }
}
```

And last but certainly not least, my `process(YunClient client)`. Here is where the biggest changes happened (at least Arduino-side).

Taking the link Q_ro suggested as a guide, changed my REST calls from my original structure (`arduinoyun.local/arduino/estado/PIN`) where I had an individual "webpage" per PIN, to a new structure (`arduinoyun.local/arduino/estado`) where I would put all my currently monitored PINs in a single "webpage" as a JSON object (an array, in this case).

I want to make a special remark here: during my testing, I came to realize (the hard way) the importance of trimming whitespaces. Don't know why so don't ask me, but it wasn't until I did *`command.trim();`* that my code worked. Maybe the browser inserts some whitespaces when querying the page or something, I dunno. What I do know is that was already banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why `arduinoyun.local/arduino/estado` wouldn't bring out anything by the time I noticed the `trim()` in Grallator's code.

Anyway, after the command is properly verified, I print a header that tells the browser this is a JSON object.

After that, I just print out an array with this form: `[value, value, value]`. You can get all the details in the *Sources*.

And that's about it on this side of the equation.

**HTML and JavaScript**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Cambio de CSS con JSON</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var Timer =setInterval(function(){cambiarColor()},500);
        function cambiarColor(){
        var i=0;
        $.getJSON("/arduino/estado/",function(json){
            var LENGTH = json.length;
            for(i; i < LENGTH; i++){
                if(json[i]==0){
                    $("#puerta"+i).css("color","green");
                } else{
                    $("#puerta"+i).css("color","red");
                }//cierra if
            }//cierra for
        }); //cierra $.getJSON
    } //cierra cambiarColor();
    </script>

  </head>
    <body>
    <p id="puerta0">Puerta 1</p>
    <p id="puerta1">Puerta 2</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

`var Timer =setInterval(function(){cambiarColor()},500);` simply sets up a timer so that function `cambiarColor()` is called upon periodically.

As per `cambiarColor()` itself, it's changed quite a bit. You can read up on the details of how function `$.getJSON` works in the **Sources**, but here's the gist:

- assuming the JSON object is properly formatted server-side, $-getJSON() returns either a JS object or a JS array (an array in my case)
- pass the array to variable `json`
- create a variable to hold the length of the `json` array
- do a `for loop` to go through the values inside of `json`
- **change CSS values using jQuery based on the values of the JSON object, obtained from the Arduino** *yaaaayyy*

@Q_ro I found out how to concatenate the `i` to the jQuery selector so that I could work by IDs! Wooo!

So there you go. Once again, bunch of thanks to Q_ro for helping me out. Hope that this is useful to somebody else in the future.

One tip to remember (I know I forgot about this for longer than I care to admit): the $.getJSON section of the code is closed with a `});`, not just a `}`.

**Sources**

- http://grallator.wordpress.com/2014/01/13/json-and-the-arduino-yun/
- http://jquerytipsntricks.wordpress.com/2013/07/06/parse-json-data-using-jquery-getjson/
- json(dot)org (site is being derpy and won't let me add more than 2 links)
- api(dot)jquery(dot)com

There's a bunch of helpful tools at the end of that last page. jsoneditoronline(dot)org in particular proved quite useful to me; helped me visualize the JSON object structure a little better.

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT 2

Well, since your last comment, i think it may be worth it for you to try this out and see what happens:

```
    var response ;
    var file_path = 'path/to/your/file.txt';

     $.ajax({
                url: file_path,
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'text',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    response = data;
                }
            });
    //this should, in theory get you the inner contents of your file, and assign it to the variable 
    "response".

    //now you can validate

    if(parseInt(response) == 0){
                        //i still think using $('#puerta1') as the DOM selector is better.
                        $('p:nth-child(1)').css('color','green');
                    } else{
                        $('p:nth-child(1)').css('color','red');
                    }

                    $('p:nth-child(2)').css('color','blue');
        });

//if nothin' happens, try and uncomment the next line to try and find what jquery is reading from your file:
//alert(response);
```

I think this should be it, or at least i'm getting closer to undertanding your problem and finding a possible solution.

## EDIT

Reading your question once again, i think i finally undesrtood what you are trying to do here, and so, i think the answer to your problem is as follows :

```
//The url to the webpage where arduino is outputing the values
$.get( "URLTOMYWEBPAGE.HTML").done(function( data ) {
if( parseInt(data ) == 0){
                //i still think using $('#puerta1') as the DOM selector is better.
                $('p:nth-child(1)').css('color','green');
            } else{
                $('p:nth-child(1)').css('color','red');
            }

            $('p:nth-child(2)').css('color','blue');
});
```

Hope this is in fact the solution to your problem.

## OLD

Im not sure of what you are tryign to do on this line `"if(1==0)"` that's always gonna be false, i also don't really undertand how you are getting the values you want to read and evaluate onto your web page, but, lets say, the values (1 and 0 from what i understood) are going to be inside the P elements, that is to say, your html is gonna look ad follows:

```
<!-- assuming this values where returned from arduino -->
<p id="puerta1">1</p>
<p id="puerta2">0</p>
```

Asuming, all of the above is true, your script would look as follows:

```
var puertaUNO = document.getElementById("puerta1").innerHTML;
var puertaDOS = document.getElementById("puerta2").innerHTML;

if( parseInt(puertaUNO) == 0){
                $('p:nth-child(1)').css('color','green');
            } else{
                $('p:nth-child(1)').css('color','red');
            }

            $('p:nth-child(2)').css('color','blue');
```

Or with Jquery

```
var puertaUNO = $('#puerta1').text();
 var puertaDOS = $('#puerta2').text();

if( parseInt(puertaUNO) == 0){
                    $('#puerta1').css('color','green');
                } else{
                    $('#puerta1').css('color','red');
                }

                $('#puerta2').css('color','blue');
```

Still not entirely to clear on what you wanna do, but i think this is it.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for helping me out here.

I changed the content of `cambiarColor` to what you suggested (`$.get("...`) but the script stopped working altogether (or at least I think so, since the second `<p>` wont turn blue anymore).

I'm not too sure how much this might matter, but the "webpages" aren't HTML; they are just ASCII. If I open those on a browser and see their source code, all I'll see is  a 0 or a 1, no `<html>` or `<body>` tags.

I did try appending the .html to the address in the script just to see what happened, but it didn't work either.

Comment: when you say "ascii" you mean, plain text files, as in txt ?.

Comment: EDIT2: I tried that as well. Didn't work. While I do say the "webpages" are ASCII, these are not .txt files either. This is how my URLs look like and what it shows: http://i59.tinypic.com/do6tle.jpg You could say that the content is "generated" the moment I try to access the URL. Maybe it's not working because I'm not putting the code where I should. What I did was take the code you posted and put it like this `function cambiarColor(){CODECODECODE}`, all this within the `<script>` tags. I am pretty new to the whole HTML design thing, so please excuse me if I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: You may want to check this post :

http://grallator.wordpress.com/2014/01/13/json-and-the-arduino-yun/

even tho its nto entirely related to your question, there is a segment of the post where they set up a system for comunicating the information of a sensor back to a webpage using jSON, this looks like the way to go to try and solve your problem ;); but i'm thinking the solution to your problem is probably is just a matter of seting the following line son your YUN file :  client.println("Status: 200");
 client.println("Content-type: application/text");

Comment: Thanks, Q_ro. I tried adding the Status and Content-type lines to my code just before `client.print(estado[puerta])` but still didn't work. When directly accesing the "webpages", I get an error ("failed to execute file dispatcher..."). I had already seen that post by Grallator and hadn't found anything usefull, but I took a better look this time and I found a part in his .js file where he uses an `if` on the data hosted by his Arduino. this might indeed be the solution I need, but first I need to wrap my head around his code (like I said, I'm new to JS and I have no idea what JSON is)

Comment: well, i'm really new to yun, just heard of it ('cause of you :P), but im doing my best to try and help you, hope you can figure out what the real problem is, 'cause, how i see it, it seems like this should work.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help you've given me, Q_ro. Right now, I'm trying to write my js function to work with JSON objects like Grallator's, but like I said, I'm new to JS so I'm taking it slow. Also, just as an FYI: I found out why I had that error with the Status:200 prefix you suggested before: it was missing a blank like after the Content-type. Now when I access the "webpages" I indeed download a text file with a 0/1. The file has no extension, tho; but since I'm using linux, that's no biggie. Gave your ajax solution a second try but still no good.